# paypal integration and testing

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, sandbox

I use sandbox for simple pay, my form is:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="paypal">
    <input type="hidden" value="_cart" name="cmd">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="upload">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="no_note">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="no_shipping">
    <input type="hidden" value="USD" name="currency_code">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{my external script here[http://example.com]}}" name="notify_url">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{my email}}" name="business">
    <input type="hidden" value="Eko " name="item_name_1">
    <input type="hidden" value="107-372" name="item_number_1">
    <input type="hidden" value="0.50" name="amount_1">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity_1">
    <input type="hidden" value="E-mail" name="item_name_2">
    <input type="hidden" value="Free Shipping" name="item_number_2">
    <input type="hidden" value="0.00" name="amount_2">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity_2">
    <input type="hidden" value="0.23" name="tax_cart">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="discount_amount_cart">
    <input type="hidden" value="http://test.t/put-log.php" name="return">
    <input type="hidden" value="http://test.t/raw.html" name="cancel_return">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

After submit this form I pay using another sandbox account. My payment is correct but Im not redirecting to notify_url, looks like my IPN is lost or not sending, maybe because sandbox mode or any other idea?

**SOLVED**
My sandbox account misconfiguration - added verfication (bank account) to sandbox account and now history logs looks ok

Thanks for help!!

Comment: does your "notify_url" pointing to LIVE URL?

Comment: yes, my script on live url just puts logs into txt file with POST and GET content

Comment: looks like my IPN is lost or not sending-> did you check your IPN history ?

Comment: when i login on sandbox account there isn't any IPN logs but when i login on developer i see users has message about accepted pays...

Answer (score 0):

notify_url is for IPN which is completely separate from the checkout flow.  No redirection will take place with your notify_url.  The redirect would be the "return" parameter and could be used with PDT, which is similar to IPN, however, the user is never guaranteed to make it back to your return URL so it's not recommended to handle any post-transaction processing with PDT.

IPN is what you want, but you have to remember it's separate from the checkout flow.  Check the IPN History from the sandbox account you're using as the seller.  Also check your web server logs.  It could be that the IPN is getting triggered but you have an error in your script keeping it from running correctly. IPN History and your web server logs will help you track this down.